# Why this simple code causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, struct, exc-bad-access

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int offset;
} Node;

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        Node node = {111111};
        NSValue *value = [NSValue value:&node withObjCType:@encode(Node)];
        [array addObject:value];

        NSValue *structValue = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        Node *n = (Node *)[structValue pointerValue];

        printf("offset: %d", n->offset);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code crashes on this line: `printf("offset: %d", n->offset);` but why?

Comment: What happens if you examine the contents of 'n' prior to the printf line?

Comment: I just couldn't access `n->offset`, but `printf("%d", n)` outputs `111111`. But if I add another field to the `Node` struct, `printf("%d", n)` only prints the value of the first field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to get c-value back is `getValue:`:

```
Node n;
[structValue getValue:&n];
```

`pointerValue` does not return a pointer to stored value, it reads a pointer value from memory where the `Node` is stored (like `union { Node n; void* pointerValue; }`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a pointer and receive a pointer use `NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithPointer:&node];` instead.